# (Resolved) Eclipse Repeats actions that produce pop up windows

Tags: c, eclipse

Downloaded & Installed/unzipped Eclipse 2020-9  to see if my old version ( Mars ) was broken.

When I do something simple like
[Add a Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBuD5.png)

I get two "create folder dialogues"
[2 popups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXWjt.png)

Same when I right click to delete a folder, I get two delete dialogue boxes.
these are just two examples, I'm guessing most actions will have two reactions!

Cannot debug a target get an error ( Stop the first session before staring a new one )
guessing Run->Debug is fired twice too.

I'm a long time eclipse user, so really curious why this is happening
issue started when I got a 'new' win 7 pc, discovering this bug while setting up my environment

any hints are welcome.

Used OpenJDK and Oracles Java 8  same issue  ( Tried two versions of eclipse, same issue )

Eclipse is used for C development with ARM MCUs  with OpenOCD and Gcc for ARM.

Many thanks for taking time to read this.

Regards
Alan

**Solution:
Fixed nVidia graphic driver application software was the culprit, the one that makes enhances the user experience by making windows go transparent when you drag them, good useful stuff like that. Uninstall nVidia desktop enhancing tools and Eclipse (and Notepad++ ) work perfectly Eclipse was never the problem, just the side effect.**

Comment: I think I've had this bug too in the past but I don't remember how it was fixed, if at all. I don't think it's a new bug anyway. Could have something to do with importing existing projects into the workspace, doing so was always a complete clusterf*.

Comment: How have you been able to run Eclipse 2020-09 that requires Java 11 or higher, and what result did you get? On Linux, that might be an issue of an outdated GTK. Can this be reproduced in Eclipse 2020-09? Which OS do you have (if Linux, also what GTK version do you have)?

Comment: @howlger I just downloaded a zip file from eclipse.org
"eclipse-cpp-2020-09-R-win32-x86_64.zip"  extracted it and ran the eclipse.exe file

This has the same behaviour as MARS
tried both with new work spaces and projects but still same behaviour

Comment: I just tried it but I'm not able to reproduce this with `eclipse-cpp-2020-09-R-win32-x86_64.zip` on Windows 10. Which Windows version do you have? Do you have some mouse tools or something like that installed in your Windows?

Comment: @howlger I'm win 7, Has logitech set point installed, but had removed it. 
I'm at a loss.   Might just have to ue the old machine to fire up my favourite IDE :(

Comment: @Lundin Thank you both for your help.

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you create a completely new project/workspace vs importing an old one?

Comment: @Lundin Yes, So fresh install, Fresh workspace, brand new project.

Just tried on my work PC, and its perfect....
my 'new' win 7 has issues...   
So i'm guessing what PC environment would cause this....
Ruled out JRE ( its shipped with eclipse 2020-9 )
Ruled out mouse interaction 
Ruled out Old projects and settings ( I deleted c:\users\me\.eclipse   and all eclipse related junk in there )

Comment: is there a way to see what eclipse calls when I click one of its context or main menu items?  I dont even know how to phrase that to get sensibel google hits

Comment: [Eclipse 2019-12 (4.14)](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2019-12/r/eclipse-ide-cc-developers) was the latest [for Windows 7](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/plans/eclipse_project_plan_4_14.xml#target_environments). The current release, Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17), supports [only Windows 10](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/plans/eclipse_project_plan_4_17.xml#target_environments). But maybe updating of at least CDT will work.

Comment: Fixed  nVidia graphic driver application software was the culprit, the one that makes enhances the user experience by making windows go transparent when you drag them,  good useful stuff like that.
Eclipse was never the problem, just the side effect

Than you both for your time!

Comment: You might add your finding as an answer to help others.